# javascript object Dynamic set?

Tags: javascript

How can I dynamically set `theName` and change it?  Is there  a way to do that?

```
var myTeam = new Object ();

 function AddObject(theName) {

   var person = new Object();
   person.firstName = "John";
   person.lastName = "Doe";
   person.age = 50;
   person.eyeColor = "blue";

  myTeam.theName =  person;
}

AddObject("Example1");
AddObject("Example2");
AddObject("Example3");
```

Comment: yes? I'm not sure I know what your question is? It looks like you've already done that with `myTeam.theName =  person;`

Comment: Do you have more code?

Comment: He wants to do `myTeam[theName] = person`. No more code is needed.

Comment: @JJJ That's a reasonable assumption, but not completely clear. Don't know what to vote.

Comment: @Oriol I think it's obviously what he wants. `theName` is a parameter to the function, so it's a variable, not a literal property name.

Comment: Jackpot: myTeam[theName] = person

Comment: Jackpot: myTeam[theName] = person

Thanks, that did it! My first time working with objects.. ;)